# Codeigniter: Click on a link then get value from checked checkboxes to pass to controller

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox, php

I have three menus(ADD, EDIT, DELETE), and many items with checkboxs. I checked some checkboxs then when i click on DELETE, I want to delete all the checked items. I just don't know how can i detect which checkboxs are checked with codeigniter. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I put all the checkboxs in a form with one submit button. That work fine. But I need two submit button Edit and Delete to edit and delete multiple items, Just don't know how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975819/jquery-delete-id-from-element-with-ajax-of-a-database-and-refresh/10976778#10976778

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery to get the current selected items like this:

```
 var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.class_you_like').map(function () 
 {
     return this.value;
 }).get();
```

After this you can post the values to CI with ajax:

```
 $.ajax(
 {
         type: 'post',
         url: '/dummy/delete',
         data:{ids: values}
 });
```

Then in CI/PHP

```
function delete()
{
   $ids = $this->input->post('ids');

   // !this should be done in a model
   $this->db->where_in('id_column', $ids);
   $this->db->delete('your_table');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the checkbox elements in a form then give DELETE as an submit button then in your contrller

```
public function delete()
{
    $for_delete = $this->input->post('checkbox');//Hope that your all checkbox names are array of checkbox[];
    $for_delete = implode(',',$for_delete);
    $this->model_to_delete->delete($for_delete);
}
```

in your model delete all the records whose id's are there in the for_delete array()

Comment: IF my DELETE is a submit button what about my EDIT, DELETE And EDIT have similar behavior, multiple edit and multiple delete.

Comment: YOu can edit single row or record at once right...??so no need to apply the checkbox edit,it will be row wise itself.And moreover EDIT,DELETE can be the submit buttons,because a form can have multiple submit buttons